# PostgreSQL JSONB - Update key name on all rows with a single query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, jsonb

I have a jsonb field in a PostgreSQL table and I want to change only the key name, keeping the same value for it.

Currently, I'm doing this in Rails like this:

```
Event.each do |event|
   event.metadata['new_key'] = metadata['old_key']
   event.metadata.delete('old_key')
   event.save
end
```

Is there a way to achieve the same result using a single update_all query?

Comment: Top level key? Sample value? Postgres version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a top-level key and current PostgreSQL,
you can achieve this by removing the old key and adding the new - with the value copied from the old:

```
UPDATE event
SET    metadata = (metadata - 'old_key')
               || jsonb_build_object('new_key', metadata->'old_key')
WHERE  metadata ? 'old_key';  -- only where the key exists
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=fcc142bd53ef7440f3ddc66228b11ffd)*